# why mongoose won't create an ObjectID

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongodb-query, jwt

I have a JSON web token that once it's verified gives me a string that is the object id value of a user I want to find but it seems that every time I try to query with it being parsed into a mongoose object ID it never find my user, am I parsing it right ? I always get a 401 invalid token paylaod

```js
logRoute.get('/user', (req, res) => {
  let token = req.body;
  User.findOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(jwt.verify(token.token, 'secretkey').subject)}, (error, user) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } else {
      if (!user) {
        res.status(401).send('invalid token payload')
      } else {
        let userData = {firstname: user.firstname, lastname: user.lastname, type: user.type}
        res.status(200).send(userData)
      }
    }
  })
})
```

my user data

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5efc7d60ba7a8d3db08ca767"
    },
    "type": "teacher",
    "firstname": "arandomfirstname",
    "lastname": "arandomlastname",
    "login": "random1",
    "pwd": "arandompassword"
}
```

and

```js
console.log(jwt.verify(req.body.token, 'P3GPROJECT'))
```

return me

```
{ subject: '5efc7d60ba7a8d3db08ca767', iat: 1593690718 }
```

EDIT:

User model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  pwd: String,
  lastname: String,
  firstname: String,
  type: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'user');
```

Comment: I don't think that there is a problem with mongoose, I think You don't have id in Your token. Mongoose understands id even if it's a string, so make sure that `console.log(jwt.verify(req.body.token, 'P3GPROJECT'))` returns proper object.

Comment: I console logged it and the jwt verify return me the right id

Comment: please put it to Your question

Comment: I've answered to Your question and rewritten Your code in better manner.

Comment: please put schema to Your user model

Answer (score 0):

You've to remove `_id: String` from model schema, since You've `ObjectId` as a value (not a string) and it makes mongoose to convert Your input to string, instead of `ObjectId`.

so:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  pwd: String,
  lastname: String,
  firstname: String,
  type: String
});
```

becomes:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  pwd: String,
  lastname: String,
  firstname: String,
  type: String
});
```

or You can keep it as string but have to define the logic of generation of proper `_id`:

```
const uuid = require('short-uuid');
const userSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    default: uuid.generate(),  // this will generate unique string
  },
  pwd: String,
  lastname: String,
  firstname: String,
  type: String
});
```

P.S. Keep in mind if You want to use `_id: String`, You've to remove old documents or convert them manually to be `{_id: "id here"}` instead of `{_id: ObjectId("id here")}`.

Bonus:

Also I recommend You to create middlewares and separate token handling, from user authorization check.
It will allow You to not repeat access token checking in every request and will help You to understand in which step You're doing it wrong.

And then to do what You want.

1. `jwt.verify` throws error if it's invalid, that's why I put try catch arount.
2. I'm extracting `subject` as `userId` and if it does not exist it also means that token invalid, otherwise I pass handling to `next` handler in routing.
3. `authorizeUser` gets `req.accessToken.userId` from previous middleware and tries to check if user exists. If yes - so it stores complete user object in `req.user`, otherwise will end with 401 also.
4. and at last route handling goes last step which does logic or it can be empty as `res.status(200).send(req.user)`

```
const checkAccessToken = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const {subject: userId} = jwt.verify(req.body.token, 'secretkey');
    if (!userId) throw new Error('Token data does not contain user id');
    req.accessToken = {userId};
    next();
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(401).send({message: 'Invalid access token'});
  }
};

const authorizeUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const user = 
      await User.findById(req.accessToken.userId)
                .select('_id firstname lastname type')
                .lean();
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send({message: 'Unauthorized'});
    }
    req.user = user;
    req.user.id = req.accessToken.userId;
    next();
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).end();
  }
};

logRoute.get(
  '/user', 
  checkAccessToken, // checking token and putting user id to `req.user.id`
  authorizeUser,    // checking if user exists in database and putting it as `req.user` object
  async (req, res) => {  // handling some logic or simply returning `req.user` object
    // some extra logic here...
    res.status(200).send(req.user);
  }
);
```

Comment: thank you for this answer but your code return me a     {subject: id} = session;
                  ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='

Comment: my console get me a TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Object
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:752:13)
    at authorizeUser (C:\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\xxxxz\xxxx\routes\log.route.js:53:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}